# CSS Trebuchet MS vs. Photoshop Trebuchet MS

Tags: html, css, templates, fonts, webfonts

I designed a small template which uses Trebuchet MS font (PSD). Now, if I use this font in HTML/CSS it
looks quite different. Is there any possibility to achive the same or a better quality ?

Maybe Google Webfont ? Is there a simmilar font ? Or should I use CSS @font-face?

```
CSS:
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans serif;
```

Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic answer is No.

You're talking about font anti-aliasing (or font smoothing).  Photoshop gives anti-aliasing in four flavors (Sharp, Crisp, Strong, Smooth).  Browsers don't do the same thing, generally the OS will control font anti-aliasing.

more on browsers and fonts: [Type rendering: web browsers](http://blog.typekit.com/2010/10/21/type-rendering-web-browsers/)

Answer (score 1):

No, unless you can use flash generated or image fonts, etc. You're looking at the differences in how two different beasts render fonts and it's mostly stuff outside your control.

Answer (score 0):

@font-face is new and doesn't work in all browsers. In order to maintain cross browser support, you can use the JS based Cufon to deliver whatever font you want.

http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

Comment: `@font-face is new and doesn't work in all browsers`...it's actually not that new and is very well supported http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface

Comment: I guess my point was legacy support, anything prior to IE 9. Cufon, being JS based, should work in any browser that's supports JS. @font-face won't.

Comment: but I think you mean anything prior to IE4 since `@font-face` has been around since [CSS2 (1998)](http://www.zeldman.com/2009/08/17/web-fonts-and-standards/)

Comment: Trebuchet is considered web safe. http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html

Comment: Per W3C, it's not supported past IE9. "The @font-face at-rule allows you to define custom fonts. It was first defined in the CSS2 specification, but was removed from CSS2.1."
W3C Says "Note: Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions, do not support the font-face rule."

Comment: @mdmullinax: Or rather it was going to be in CSS2, but pushed back due to interoperability concerns (and Microsoft generally being Microsoft).

Comment: @Brant: I find it hard to believe that W3C would say that. W3C usually makes no comments or notes about individual browsers whatsoever.

Comment: Ah, W3Schools. W3Schools is not W3C, despite the similar names. And in this case, they're half-right and all wrong: IE8 and earlier do support the `@font-face` rule, but they don't support all font formats.